Is it right to control one channel (mediator) to examine the impact of another channel?
Suppose shock X impacts Y through two mediators/channels (A and B).
Let's imagine the following Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG):
X→→Y and X→→Y. And A and B are not correlated.
If I just want to examine the second channel (B). Is it right to control for A in the regression to study the impact of X on Y through the channel B:
Y=+X+A+
I read papers discussing "bad controls", but they do not discuss cases like this.
